# Firing an event every 10 miliseconds under a certain condition Javafx

Tags: java, events, javafx, mouseevent

Hello I am trying to fire an event every 10 milliseconds under the conditions that a drag has been detected, but the mouse has not been released. Below is the code that I wish to fire.

```
mapScroll.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, e -> {
        endX = e.getX();
        endY = e.getY();
        Bounds viewBounds = mapScroll.getViewportBounds();
        double startEndX = startX - endX;
        double startEndY = startY - endY;

        Bounds contentBounds = mapScroll.getContent().getLayoutBounds();

        double hChange = startEndX / (contentBounds.getWidth() - viewBounds.getWidth());
        double vChange = startEndY / (contentBounds.getHeight() - viewBounds.getHeight());
        mapScroll.setHvalue(mapScroll.getHvalue() + hChange);
        mapScroll.setVvalue(mapScroll.getVvalue() + vChange);

        startX = endX;
        startY = endY;
    });
```

Unfortunately before I tried using a scheduled executor service within the event, but this did not work correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure this question makes any sense. The event filter you already have will be executed once per pulse if the mouse is being dragged and changes location during that pulse - i.e. it will be executed as fast as the system can detect changes in mouse location and respond to them. Every 10ms (100Hz) is slightly faster than the target pulse rate for JavaFX (which is 60Hz), so not every change you make to the scroll pane would be rendered anyway (sometimes two changes occur in the same pulse). What are you trying to do?

Comment: @James_D I think he is trying to do something like when you drag a file or folder in windows explorer and it has many files vertically or horizontally the scroll bar is moving vertically or horizontally based on the position of the mouse(if the mouse has reached the end of window vertically or horizontally) so you can see and the other files.

Comment: In theory it should update that quickly but in practice it moves in noticeable jumps which is not what I want. I know it's not my computer since the program has little impact on the percentage of my processor I'm using or my RAM. I doubt it's a problem with my code since the same issue was present with `set Pannable(true);` so yeah...complicated stuff makes it not work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a check if 10ms elapsed since last execution. (I used a LongProperty, because of the [final restriction](http://www.lambdafaq.org/can-lambda-expressions-use-variables-from-their-environment/) with Lambdas)

```
final LongProperty timeOfLastExecute = new SimpleLongProperty(System.currentTimeMillis());

mapScroll.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, e -> {
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timeOfLastExecute.get() > 10) {
            endX = e.getX();
            endY = e.getY();
            Bounds viewBounds = mapScroll.getViewportBounds();
            double startEndX = startX - endX;
            double startEndY = startY - endY;

            Bounds contentBounds = mapScroll.getContent().getLayoutBounds();

            double hChange = startEndX / (contentBounds.getWidth() - viewBounds.getWidth());
            double vChange = startEndY / (contentBounds.getHeight() - viewBounds.getHeight());
            mapScroll.setHvalue(mapScroll.getHvalue() + hChange);
            mapScroll.setVvalue(mapScroll.getVvalue() + vChange);

            startX = endX;
            startY = endY;
            timeOfLastExecute.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation (have a look at [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/3429133) on Meta).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) which (tries to)runs at 60 frames per second.So every time 10 seconds pass you execute the code(You have to start the `AnimationTimer` every time):

---

**Code:**

```
public void startTimer(){

   AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
           int seconds;
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {

               //every time 10 seconds have passed
               //note that 1 second=1000 milliseconds=1.000.000 nanoseconds
               //now->variable which represents nano seconds
               if(now%10000000 == 0){

                  endX = e.getX();
                  endY = e.getY();
                 Bounds viewBounds = mapScroll.getViewportBounds();
                 double startEndX = startX - endX;
                 double startEndY = startY - endY;

                 Bounds contentBounds = mapScroll.getContent().getLayoutBounds();

                 double hChange = startEndX / (contentBounds.getWidth() - viewBounds.getWidth());
                 double vChange = startEndY / (contentBounds.getHeight() - viewBounds.getHeight());
                 mapScroll.setHvalue(mapScroll.getHvalue() + hChange);
                 mapScroll.setVvalue(mapScroll.getVvalue() + vChange);

                 startX = endX;
                 startY = endY;

              }
            }
        }
    }

     timer.start();

}
```

---